# How do I move a number between two Alcatel Lucent 4029 Handsets

Tags: telephone, alcatel-lucent

I'm trying to find a manual online and I'm not having any luck.  I need to know the deregister/reregister procedure for an Alcatel Lucent 4029 handset.  I'm trying to move a number from one desk to another one, so we just need to deregister handset 2, deregister handset 1 and then register the number from handset 1 onto the now blank handset 2.

All advice on whether I'm trying to do it the wrong way is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got onto IT.  For prosperity:

Pick up the handset and dial #05.

Then it will ask for a password, if your IT dept didn't change it, it's still 0000.

Then you can hang up.  To hook on the new phone (or a different number on the same phone) pick up the handset, dail your extension number and then type in the same admin password (0000 default).  Note of course you can't move the number till you deregister it from the first handset.

Answer (score 0):

To hook back on:

1. Plug in the new phone and wait for it to come back to life.
2. If your company allocates a site prefix digit to your extension, then you will need to find this first.  In my case it was 5, so with my extension it was 5XXXX where XXXX is my four digit extension.
3. Now you're ready to HOOK ON.  Lift the handset and then type in your site prefix followed by your extension.  If your system is setup without a site prefix, then your four digit extension is all that is needed (XXXX).